# Why are all getters being accessed when deserializing parameters for MVC API methods?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC Core API defined like this:

```
public async Task<ResponseInfo> ExecuteRequestInfoAsync([FromBody]RequestInfo value)
```

The RequestInfo class has many properties.  I fully expect the setter to be accessed for all of the properties as the object is deserialized; however, what I am seeing in the debugger is that all of the getters are being accessed.  This is a real problem for me.  For the property that is the source of the problem, I even have it flagged with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore, not that that should matter in this case, but I am trying anything.  Why would the getters be accessed when deserializing my input class and how to I stop it?  Thank you.

Edit:

So, it seems as though the DefaultModelBinder has been replaced with ComplexTypeModelBinder in Core.

I think this is the line causing my trouble:

```
propertyModel = property.PropertyGetter(bindingContext.Model);
```

What benefit is this step?  Is there a way to flag properties to be ignored?

Comment: This is part of the model binding process (called by the `DefaultModelBinder`), which includes validating your property values and calling its getter in that process.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, do you know why this happens, but more importantly, can I disable this functionality?  Also, is this actually the case for Core?  I did a search for DefaultModelBinder, and so far I have only been able to find references to classic .Net MVC.  I just do not see any reason why any part of the framework would need to access the getter properties of an input to my route.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a good way to get MVC to stop accessing all of the getters, so I settled for changing the signature of my method.

```
public async Task<ResponseInfo> ExecuteRequestInfoAsync(string serializedJSONOfParameter)
```

Then, I perform the deserialization, myself, of the object in my code.